# How to take dump of neo4j graph databases?

Tags: neo4j

I had my all databases stored at a location **C:\JATIN DATA\database\neo4jDatabases**. How can I take the dump of all databases individually using neo4j Dekstop.

**I had already tried neo4j-admin dump --database= --to=** this command but getting errors like **Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'n': expected  (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"neo4j-admin dump --database= --to="
 ^**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`neo4j-admin` must be run from a terminal command line -- not from the neo4j Browser.

Since you are using the Desktop, you can open a terminal window to the appropriate directory by selecting your neo4j Project from the Projects panel on the left, click the `Manage` button of the database you want to dump, And then select the `Terminal` tab.

Once in the Terminal window, you can enter a command like the one suggested by @logisma:

```
bin/neo4j-admin dump --database=graph.db --to=c:\
```

Comment: Whenever I run this command from console gives an error message **'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ** I tried in both online and offline mode

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @cybersam and @logisima finally dump is taken successfully. This is the complete command **.\bin\neo4j-admin.bat dump --database=graph.db --to=c:\dump\article_citation_graph.dump** there was some admin privilege error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this : `.\bin\neo4j-admin.bat dump --database=graph.db --to=c:\`

This should create a file named `graph.db.dump` in your `c:\` folder.

Comment: Whenever I run this command from console gives an error message **'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**  I tried in both online and offline mode

Comment: I have done a mistake on the command for WIN, so I have updated my answer. If it's not working can give the result of the command `dir` from the desktop terminal ?

Comment: Still getting some error administrative privilege like WARNING: This command does not appear to be running with administrative rights.  Some
commands may fail e.g. Start/Stop**output of dir**
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is DACA-A85F

 Directory of C:\JATIN DATA\database\neo4jDatabases\database-688492d1-aa6c-4c4d-aa6f-087c5b86b
d31\installation-3.4.0
and some other information like  
06/13/2018  03:27 PM    <DIR>          .
06/13/2018  03:27 PM    <DIR>          ..