# Neo4J dump database

Tags: neo4j

I'm looking to export my local database in Neo4J desktop on Windows. Does version 1.4.3 have the ability to dump a database through the UI? It used to be available by clicking the '...' next to a db instance.

I have also tried running command line dump according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025132/how-to-take-dump-of-neo4j-graph-databases). I open a terminal for a database and try to run the command

```
.\bin\neo4j-admin.bat dump --database=graph.db --to=c:\dump\myDb.dump
```

And it says that database `graph.db` doesn't exist. I explored the folders and found the directory `data/databases/` which as a number of `.db` files, but none are named `graph.db`. If I use the `neo4j-admin` command to dump the database, which file should I target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully dump the file. In the terminal for my database I had to use the above command with the database name.

```
.\bin\neo4j-admin.bat dump --database=MyDatabase --to=c:\dump\myDb.dump
```

Also the target folder must exist.